# Postgres Interval not working in where subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following code:

```
Select * from table
where to_date <= ( select max(to_date)
                  FROM table)
  and to_date >= (select (max(to_date)::date - interval '6 months')::date as to_date
                  FROM table)
```

Basically, I am trying to look at all the results between the max date and then 6 months in the past, and I tried doing that by making 2 sub queries.

I seem to get null, but oddly enough, if add the regular date that

```
(select (max(to_date)::date - interval '6 months')::date
```

is giving and paste it as `>='yyyy-mm-dd'`, the query seems to be working fine. It is weird as both sub-queries are actually spitting out date format results and have no idea why its giving this.

Comment: Why are you casting the value in the second query to a `date` but not in the first?

Comment: What do you mean "not working"?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need both comparison:

```
select *
from table
where to_date >= (select (max(to_date)::date - interval '6 months')::date as to_date
                  from table
                 ) ;
```

This is assuming that the table reference is the same in both the inner and outer query.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really think of a reason why this wouldn't work, but you can rewrite the query to only run a single sub-query, which is also more efficient:

```
select t.*
from the_table t
  cross join (
    select max(the_date) as max_date
    from the_table
  ) mt
where t.to_date <= mt.max_date 
  and t.to_date >= mt.max_date - interval '6 months'
```

Comment: Weird enough with the approach you suggested I get the same null result (and no, it shouldn't be null, I do have data going back 6 months)

Comment: It can only be `null` if the table contains no rows at all.